# Firebase: Securing records by email address when users can use fake addresses

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, payment

I'm making a web app where you pay to use it first and then sign in. The sign up workflow is this:

- Once a payment is made on my website, the client receives an order ID that is associated with their email address. The client sends this to a Firebase Function endpoint to activate their order.
- The Firebase Function checks the order ID is valid and creates a Firebase user with a long random password (to prevent anyone from signing in), then sends a password reset email. A "payment" record is created in Firestore and associated with the user ID.
- The user follows the password reset email then logs into my app. The paid features are activated if Firestore contains a payment associated with that user ID.

This all seems fine except:

1. A malicious user Bob could outside of my control creates a user for email "x@example.com" that he doesn't own and sign in using the Firebase client SDK.
2. Alice then makes a payment for her email "x@example.com".
3. Bob will still be signed in and can now use the features Alice paid for.

How do I prevent this?

One idea I had was the above Firebase Function could check if user "x@example.com" exists with an unverified email address and if so it would 1) delete that user and 2) create a user for that email address again (creating a new unique user ID). Bob would then have a different user ID than the one associated with the email address so couldn't access the payment record. However, this breaks if Alice makes two payments without validating her email after the first payment. What's a robust way of solving this?

Comment: This seems complicated.  Why not just have them make an account first with restricted access and relieve the restriction on payment?

Comment: @Vincent I don't want them to have to sign up first if that's what you mean. It would be added friction for collecting the first payment which would lower conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider verifying the email before processing the transaction.
One option is to use [sign in with email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth). This will sign in the user and verify their email. You can also set a password after if you want. If an existing unverified provider is linked to the account, it will be unlinked and any existing session that a malicious user had previously set up will be revoked.